# Trouble with solidify, bevel, and subdivision surface modifiers

Tags: modeling

I am trying to follow a blender tutorial and am having a problem with getting the subdivision surface modifier to work as shown in the image. Instead I wind up getting what is in the second picture. How am I supposed to get what is in the first image using just solidify, bevel, and subdivision surface modifiers and why is there a yellow and blue outline in the first image but not when I do it? Is the solidify modifier supposed to create vertices and edges to go with the extended part?
[image: what I am trying to do]

[image: What I am getting]

Edit: I cannot share the tutorial link, however I can outline the steps to certain extent from default cube that I am supposed to turn into a room.

1. change dimensions to 3.05 x, 3.05 y, and 2.74 z
2. use edit mode to select and cut away 3 of the faces and separate the bottom from the corner walls
3. go back to object mode and add solidify modifier to walls with even thickness of -0.3 m to wall and floor
4. with wall selected, ctrl + 2 and add bevel modifier- and select shift to top option (I believe this means move to first but I am not sure, I just arranged the 3 modifiers with bevel then subdivision because that is what is shown on image with solidify at the bottom)
5. change segment value to 2, shape value to max, and limit measurement to weight, changing mean bevel weight to 1

That is where I am at. I have tried using creases but that only affects one side and not both, and going by the differences in the blue and orange outlines it looks like my solidify is extruding without creating edges and vertices to accommodate the new dimensions while the one in the tutorial is.

Solution: I figured it out. I didn't realize that there was an apply option that was different than simply shifting the modifier order on the list. It wasn't mentioned in the instructions, but apparently until I did that my wall was being registered as a 2d object instead of 3d because the thickness was just a modifier on the 2d faces. After hitting apply, the object I was working on was recognized as being 3d in shape and not just 2d with a little thickness. What a pain, useful if you know about it, but still a pain.

Comment: See if turning the number of Segments on the Bevel Modifier down to 1 cures it. If not, give a link to the tutorial and share your Blend file: https://blend-exchange.com/.

Comment: Your modifiers are in the correct order, which is important. Beginners sometimes use them in the wrong order and don't understand the result. Still, I can't reproduce what's on the first image. Maybe you forgot a step while setting up? I can obtain a similar result by bevelling the edges with ctrl+B, not sure if this is what was shown in the tut.

Comment: it would help if you could add a link to the tutorial you are following...